# Maximise the battery life on a mac

Tags: linux, mac, battery

I would like to run linux on my macbook (4GB memory, 1.4GHz Intel Core i5 processor). However, when I tried to do so (using scientific linux 7) then the battery life was greatly reduced, even though I installed it on a partition instead of running it on a usb. The laptop was also much hotter and louder, but I was not running any particularly resource-intensive software.

Are there any drivers or programs for Linux designed specifically for mac hardware can preserve the good battery life under OSX? Or are there any distributions other than scientific linux that are specifically optimised for battery life?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Linux as a side operating system, or are you replacing OS X entirely. If you are not replacing OS X, but rather running them both at the same time, the battery drainage and overheating of the system is because the processor has to run both OS X and Linux at the same time, using up more resources than just OS X.